# IIS host website

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting

I have my asp.net web application in IIS, it works fine if I'm on my computer and type my ip-address/Default.aspx, But when i tried to access it on a diff computer, it doesn't work, it took me some search engine instead. How do i do this?

Comment: the answer below is good, however try modifying your firewall, if still no success please put a comment and i will follow with you till your app is up and running